# import only specific module in jenkins groovy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have added some changes to x-jenkins groovy file which is to call y-jenkins functions (.groovy files under /var. in y-jenkins repo) - sorry if my terminology is correct as I am not familiar with jenkins. Now in my pipeline's jenkinsfile, used below to try to import from y-jenkinsfile

```
@Library('x-jenkinsfile@master') _
@Library('y-Jenkinsfile@master')
```

Due to above its importing all the functions in y-jenkins and conflicting with x-jenkins functions having same names. Is there any way to import specific functions/methods (.groovy files under /var. in y-jenkins repo) into my jenkinsfile?

Could not find the info I am looking for in this link - https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Comment: The answer is in your link : https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#loading-libraries-dynamically
You can use a function like this

Comment: Thanks, but that section shows how to import classes from src folder and for var it imports all the files. I am looking to import specific file from var directory. How to do that?